# IntelliJ IDEA and Google Chrome fail to connect for JavaScript debugging

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, intellij-idea, google-chrome-extension, jetbrains-ide

JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA sometimes loses its own JetBrains IDE Support plugin in Chrome. Upon debugging in IDEA, Chrome complains that:

> hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji is blocked
>
> Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension

and stays on this page:

```
chrome-extension://hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji/loading.html?__QUERY__
```

Where `hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji` is JetBrains' plugin ID.

Instead of redirecting to the target page of the form:

```
http://localhost:63342/__PROJECT__/__PATH__/index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Restarting Google Chrome or disabling-and-enabling IDE Support plugin helps. IDEA "finds" Chrome again and `Debug` workflow works as intended.

Another possible problem is a failed authorization.

To debug a URL like this:

```
http://localhost:63342/__PROJECT__/__PATH__/index.html
```

Open it in the browser *before* starting to debug. It'll give `404 Not Found`. Then switch back to IDEA and it will offer you to `Copy authorization URL to clipboard`:

```
http://localhost:63342/__PROJECT__/__PATH__/index.html?_ijt=__KEY__
```

Open this URL.

After this manual authentication is complete, IntelliJ IDEA should be able to debug `index.html` in Chrome.

IDEA always opens `index.html` for debugging in the browser window where the latest authentication happened. E.g., in a Chrome Incognito window, instead of a Chrome "normal" window, if you've just authorized IDEA in Incognito.

Going incognito may require an additional setup:

- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206201319-launching-chrome-incognito-in-intellij-12

Comment: Do you setup your project in IntelliJ with a JavaScript Debug run/debug configuration? How did you determine `__PROJECT__/__PATH__`?